# Editing Document Set Properties Issue

Tags: document-library, document-set

I am currently having some issues being able to edit the properties of a Document Set after it is created.

My main library on my site is a Digital Assets library. After adding in a few pictures, I decided I wanted to try out the Document Set, so I added the content type to my Library and added in few columns from the list to add to them.

The issue comes when I try to edit it. I only get the Content Type field (I have an option of a Document Set or a Folder) and the Name (which is marked as required). The Dialog Box seems to be sized incorrectly as well.

It seems to be only this Library that is affected by this issue, if I create a new library and try to add a Document Set content type to it, it seems to work.

Is there some setting I have in my Digital Assets Library that is preventing the Document Set from working properly or is there some limitation of the Document Set that I am unaware of?